# Freeform Lite, input error message translation

Tags: solspace-freeform, translation

The main message error could be translated through template code:

```
 {if form:has_errors}
            <div class="callout alert">
                There was an error submitting this form.. 
            </div>
 {/if}
```

But the input message error: `This field is required` could be translated only by translating `'This field is required'` inside this file: 
`system/user/addons/freeform_next/Library/Composer/Components/AbstractField.php`

```
 $errors[] = $this->translate('This field is required');
```

[image]

So, how to translate the `"This field is required"` message error without to modify the AbstractField.php file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating in EE isn't the most robust, and as far as I understand, it has to be done with a translation file placed inside the add-on's language folder. You can just open up `/system/user/addons/freeform_next/language/english/freeform_next_lang.php`

Then copy and paste that into a folder with your language name at `/system/user/addons/freeform_next/language/`

And add lines like this:

```
'{email} is not a valid email address' => '{email} your translation here',
​'This field is required' => 'Your translation here',
```

​
If you wish, we can include any translations you provide us with in future releases of Freeform. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply and great solution. Problem solved ! I had a look to freeform_next_lang.php,  but I did not think about this solution.

Comment: Sure, I will send you french and portuguese traduction!